# How can I add a "for" in a Highcharts series?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a .php file which executes a query, this query adds textfields depending on the results, for example:

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT YEAR,PERIOD FROM users");
$num_users = mysqli_num_rows($query);

for($i=1; $i<=$num_users; $i++) {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

   echo "<input type='text' id='year$i' name='year$i' value='".$row['YEAR']."'>";
   echo "<input type='text' id='period$i' name='period$i' value='".$row['PERIOD ']."'>";
}
echo "<input type='text' id='count' name='count' value='$num_users'>"
```

So this would output x-number of inputs, so it may be from 1 to 40 inputs containing the year and the period, I then catch the values of this fields with the following:

```
count = parseInt(document.getElementById('count').value);
for(i=1;i<=count;i++) {
    var custom = "year" + i;
    window[custom] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('year' + i).value);
    var custom = "period" + i;
    window[custom] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('period' + i).value);
 }
```

Until this point everything works well, I've tested the above code and all the inputs values are being saved in the right variable.

How can I have a series in which will display theses ages having in mind that the number of data will change?

I was thinking something like this:

```
series: [
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++) {
     {
        name: year + i,
        data: [period + i]
     }
  }
]
```

Please help me!! THANKS!!

Comment: You cannot put a `for` in an array declaration like that. However, you should check out underscore.js for some useful functions that will help you, probably `map` in this case

Answer (score 1):

`series` must be an array.  If you want to use a function that populates that array you can create a self executing function like this (updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4XAYh/1/), it will output to a textarea):

```
series: (function(year, period, count) {
  var data = [];
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++) {
    data.push(
      {
        name: year + i,
        data: [period + i]
      }
    );
  }
  return data;
})(year, period, count)
```

This assumes you have external values `year`, `period` and `count`

Comment: I'm sorry could you explain the code a little more, I understad what you are doing but where would this go?

Comment: You could put this code in place of the for loop you wanted to use.  The wrapping `()(year, period, count)` lets you call the function you just defined with the externally defined `year`, `period` and `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy. Call

> addSeries()

in each iteration of the count and push it into the highcharts.

More info
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-addseries/

> $(function () {
>       $('#container').highcharts({
>           xAxis: {
>               categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
>           },
>           series: [{
>               data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
>           }]
>       });
>
> ```
> // the button handler
> $('#button').click(function() {
>     var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
>     if (chart.series.length == 1) {
>         chart.addSeries({
>             data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]
>         });
>     }
> }); });
> ```

Comment: This would work but what I want is to have one basic line.  So lets say today I check and have 5 dots but then I check tomorrow and the charts has 7 dots on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all but I found a more simple solution:

```
var year = new Array();

for(i=1;i<=count;i++) {
  var custom = "year" + i;
  window[custom] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('year' + i).value);
  year.push(document.getElementById('year' + i).value);
}
// Highcharts
series: [{
   name: 'Pacientes',
   data: year
}
```